# How to attribute a datatype in a MySQL column which receives an array?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, database, jdbc

I'm programming in Java and I have a input dialog which set the attributes in the columns and I have one column called "Notes" which must receive an array.

My columns:

1. Name: (patient's name), [varchar].
2. CPF: (is a personal number that Brazilians uses to identify yourself, everybody has one), [varchar].
3. Tel: (patient's telephone number), [varchar].

and finally I have:

> Notes: (patient's progress during the sessions), [??]

I don't know which Data Type I should use for this notes because they must be an array. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use another table for notes. With a one to many relationship.
[image: Database structure]

You would then get all the notes using the folowing query:

```
SELECT `content`
FROM `Note`
JOIN `Patient`
ON `Note`.`Patient_name` = `Patient`.`name`
WHERE `Patient`.`name` = 'target name here'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that I problably should do it.